# How to make a select list option selected

Tags: php, forms

I receive a variable from the mysql database named $option which in this case could be '1' or '2'. What is the correct PHP code to add the 'selected="selected"' code to $option 1 the corresponding option in the list?

```
<select name="select-list">
<option value='1'>option 1</option>
<option value='2'>option 1</option>             
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="select-list">
<option value='1' <?php if ($option == '1') { echo "selected"; } ?>>option 1</option>
<option value='2' <?php if ($option == '2') { echo "selected"; } ?>">option 1</option>             
</select>
```

like this?

Comment: downvote is done when the answer is wrong. Since you edited it, I removed the downvote. Happy answering :)

Comment: `($option == '1' && $option != '2')` is rather redundant... if the first is true the second will always be true, and vice versa. Just write `($option == '1')`.

Comment: thanks for the tip. so actually should be like

`<option value='1' <?php if ($option == '1) { echo "selected" } ?>>option 1</option>`

Comment: @Dzoki Yes, that would be more concise (just don't forget the closing `'` after the 1).

Comment: Correct, but to further expand, the first `<option>` is selected by default, so if it's not the second one, you don't need to add anything at all.

Comment: Parallism/explicitness isn't a bad thing, though. (For instance, if someone decided to change the order of the options as displayed.)

Comment: Right, however $option == '1' could mean that option 1 is anything other than false since '1' could be seen as true or not empty.  So, you should typecast the source of the var then use the === sign as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
<?php
    $select-list = (str) $_POST['select-list'];  //or however you retrieve this value
?>

<select name="select-list">
<option value='1' <?php if($select-list === "1"){ echo "selected"; }?>>option 1</option>
<option value='2' <?php if($select-list === "2"){ echo "selected"; }?>>option 1</option>             
</select>
```

Comment: Nope, still wrong. The varaible `$option` is defined to have come from the mysql query, the OP stated that, no one ever talked about the `$_POST`.

Comment: Not sure of you even read the answer Rikudo but it says "or however you retrieved this value."

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `selected` property to the item you want selected.

```
<select name="select-list">

    <option value='1'>option 1</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if ($option === '2') { echo "selected" } ?>>option 2</option>             

</select>
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.  You need to make sure 1st you show that option is being set to the $_POST and second, you need to use the === sign instead.  When your done with that, you should stop marking others questions down to get yours at the top.

Comment: I didn't mark anyone to get my answer to the top, I marked their answers because they plain wrong. And it doesn't matter if its == or === as as the result (in case coming from the database) will always be a string. No one ever said it should be set to the $_POST.

Comment: How exactly is mine wrong? and upvoting another user answer is the immaturity here, and I suggest we stop it here.

Comment: For starters, your can't be sure the 2 here is a string...  I do see that you changed your answer per my suggestion to have the === comparison operator already, yet 2 could come in as an integer or a string depending on how they get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4108/discussion-between-rikudo-sennin-and-espradley)